# Java Google Api application Default credentials

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, vision-api

How do I declare the application credentials? I have my `.json` file which is the key.

```
package shyam;

// Imports the Google Cloud client library

import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature.Type;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Image;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
    // the "close" method on the client to safely clean up any remaining background resources.
    
    try (ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {

      // The path to the image file to annotate
      String fileName = "./resources/wakeupcat.jpg";

      // Reads the image file into memory
      Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
      byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
      ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

      // Builds the image annotation request
      List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
      Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
      Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.LABEL_DETECTION).build();
      AnnotateImageRequest request =
          AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
      requests.add(request);

      // Performs label detection on the image file
      BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
      List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

      for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
        if (res.hasError()) {
          System.out.format("Error: %s%n", res.getError().getMessage());
          return;
        }

        // for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getLabelAnnotationsList()) {
        //   annotation
        //       .getAllFields()
        //       .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.format("%s : %s%n", k, v.toString()));
        // }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error

> Application default credentials are not available

I have already set it in my cmd using set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='key_path'`. I have a lot initialized my Google Cloud Account in the cli. Hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: There must be something incorrect with the environment variable. You can also setup ADC with this command: **gcloud auth application-default login**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I'm now getting the following error.. WARNING: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

Comment: That is a normal message. Read the link so that you understand the difference between user and service account credentials. You can also set up the CLI with a service account. For development using user credentials is OK, but for production set up a service account in your Java application.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help.  I managed to fix it. Thank you